# SQL Stored Procedure IF ELSE logic error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement an insert stored procedure. Basically, how it works is the `stored procedure` will check whether the record exists or not, then proceed to perform insert. A variable `@status` will be used as indicator. However, I found out a particular problem with this `query` is that when I execute the `query`, it will return the result `@status = 1` no matter the data existed or not. However, the `INSERT` function is fine without any problems just the `@status`. The following is my implementation:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE save_proc
(
  @userid varchar(10)
  @name varchar(30)
)

AS

DECLARE @status int

  if exists ( SELECT * FROM table1 where userID = @userid AND userName = @name)
    SET @status = 0

  else
    INSERT INTO table1 (userID, userName) VALUES (@userid, @name)
    SET @status = 1

SELECT @status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put it in `BEGIN END`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE save_proc
(
  @userid varchar(10)
  @name varchar(30)
)

AS

DECLARE @status int

  if exists ( SELECT * FROM table1 where userID = @userid AND userName = @name)
    SET @status = 0

    else
    begin
        INSERT INTO table1 (userID, userName) VALUES (@userid, @name)
        SET @status = 1
    end
```

If you are not putting the BEGIN END then the scope of your else statement is just the next line which is getting executed ie, `INSERT INTO table1 (userID, userName) VALUES (@userid, @name)` is only under the scope of `else` block. And `SET @status = 1` is outside the scope of `else` block. So once the `else` block executes the next query will be executed which is `SET @status = 1`

**On a side note:**

When you are checking for `if exists` then don't use the `*` wildcard. Instead you can use `1` i.e,

```
if exists ( SELECT 1 FROM table1 where userID = @userid AND userName = @name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else
begin
    INSERT INTO table1 (userID, userName) VALUES (@userid, @name)
    SET @status = 1
end
```

Modify code as above. You haven't defined scope of your else. It was upto insert statement only. SET @status = 1 was executed everytime